# Do Checkout Totals sort Order changes calculation also

Tags: magento2

I debugged through System->Configuration->Sales->Sales->Checkout Totals sort Order settings and understand that it changes the display order in totals section on cart page.
Do it affect the calculations also. For example can it make a difference in final grand total, in case shipping is shown above or after tax.